# find a time today and yesterday

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to find a time today and yesterday in sql query.
My example is in error and does not find all the rows.
Database is sql oracle.
I would be grateful for any help.
example:

```
and  (to_char(zsd.SB_ACTUAL+600/1440, 'dd.mm.yyyy') > to_char(current_date-1, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

Comment: what error shown?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  The logic isn't clear on what you want to do.

Comment: Why do you compare `VARCHAR2` values when you actually need to compare `DATE` values?

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam, apparently no error but TO does not get desired result.

Comment: I does not get desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you converting the dates into strings?

```
and  zsd.SB_ACTUAL/* If necessary, add your calculation here */ > sysdate-1
```

Or use `TRUNC()` if you want to ignore the time attribute :

```
and  TRUNC(zsd.SB_ACTUAL) /* If necessary, add your calculation here */ > TRUNC(sysdate-1)
```

Comment: I does not get desired result